# How show MKCircle on map without animation

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How show/remove MKCircle overlay on/from the map without animation?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "without animation"?  What animation are you seeing?

Comment: When i removing overlay it removing from map with animation ( with fading)